# GitKraken won't open

Tags: git, macos, gitkraken

I've been using GitKraken for a year now with no issues. Then today I go to open it and the app immediately crashes. I have tried restarting my machine (Mac). I've tried reinstalling the app. No luck.

Comment: Try to open it from terminal, maybe you'll see some errors in the output.

Comment: I'd recommend getting in touch with the creators https://www.gitkraken.com/contact

Comment: Since this is a Mac you could also open the Console.app and see what messages pop up when you try to open it.  I doubt anyone can help you without some diagnostic info.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Somehow the `.gitkraken` config file got corrupted. Maybe a new update doesn't work with an old config schema? I don't know. But the way to fix it is delete the `.gitkraken` and let a new one get generated on the next app open. This means you will need to sign in and clone your repo again.

> Steps: (Mac)
>
> 1. Open your finder and navigate to `/Users/{user}`.
> 2. Show the hidden files.
>
>    > CMD + SHIFT + .
> 3. Delete the `.gitkraken` folder.
>
> Steps: (Win)
>
> 1. Open explorer and navigate to `%appdata%`.
> 2. Delete the `.gitkraken` folder.

Then fire up the GitKraken app. Good as new.

Comment: This works! Reinstalling the app doesnt help, but this did it.

Comment: any idea for windows 10?

Comment: This works but all my profiles gone. When copied from old .gitkraken folder problem reappeared. I wish GK would introduce a fixing tool for this problem to save our profiles.

Comment: Sometimes just deleting the latest update folder also works.

Answer (score 12):

I would stay away from deleting .gitkraken until after you have exhausted all other avenues.

For me, opening a previous GitKraken version, running it and then waiting for it to update and restart sorted the issue for me.

So (on windows):

1. Navigate to %APPDATA%\Local\gitkraken\app-
2. Run gitkraken.exe from there.
3. Wait for the gitkraken ui to prompt for update and restart

Comment: Worked beautifully for me. No reinstall, no deleting or re-cloning. Great success.

Comment: Note: Step 2 should emphasise "select a previous version of GitKraken". This worked for me. I had already deleted .gitkraken, from the previous answer - which didn't fix the problem. Gitkraken then started without cached values and I had to login to github again, and get a token. Still, it all worked smoothly from there. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For me installing a new version downloaded from [The Gitkraken download page](https://www.gitkraken.com/download) fixed the issue.